# Why is the degree of the node pictured 5, not 4?

Tags: graph-theory

On the [Wikipedia page for degree (graph theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)), the bottom-right vertex pictured is said to have a degree of 5.

[image]

My understanding is that the degree of a vertex is defined as the number of edges incident to the vertex. In this case, it appears as if the bottom-right vertex has 4 edges incident to it: {2,5}, {3,5}, {2,5}, and {5,5}. So isn't the degree of the lower-right vertex 4, not 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But it enters the vertex twice. I'll try to present a few additional reasons to count it twice.

What can you say about the total sum of degrees in a graph? It's an even number, equal to $2 \cdot \#E$, where $\#E$ is the number of edges. This would fall apart if you counted such edges only once.

Also, imagine that it was a directed graph. You'd need the info that the edge both enters and exists vertex $5$.

Comment: Ah, so edges are counted twice if they are doubly incident to a vertex? Or is my definition of the term degree too simple?

Also, I just learned the First Theorem of Graph Theory, which you reference in the second paragraph of your post, so your explanation makes a lot of sense in that light.

Comment: Your definition is fine for "loopless" graphs. (A "loop" is an edge joining a vertex to itself.) With loops allowed, then yes, an edge which is doubly incident to a vertex contributes $2$ to its degree. If that sounds too arbitrary, imagine cutting each edge in the middle, leaving a half-edge attached to each endpoint; the degree of a vertex is the number of half-edges incident with it.

Comment: Excellent visualization, thank you.